# ThreeJS | Detect when an object leaves another object

Tags: javascript, three.js, collision-detection, bounding-box

I'm making a ThreeJS project in which I have **planes (Object3D)** flying inside a **sphere (Mesh)**.

I'm trying to detect the collision between a plane and the border of the sphere so I can delete the plane and make it reappear at another place inside the sphere.

My question is how do I detect when an object leaves another object ?

**The code I have now :**

```
detectCollision(plane, sphere) {

  var boxPlane = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(plane);
  boxPlane.applyMatrix4(plane.matrixWorld);

  var boxSphere = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(sphere);
  boxSphere.applyMatrix4(sphere.matrixWorld);

  return boxPlane.intersectsBox(boxSphere);

}
```

**In my render function :**

```
var collision = this.detectCollision(plane, this.radar)
  if (collision == true) {
    console.log("the plane is inside the sphere")
  }
  else {
    console.log("the plane is outside the sphere")
  }
})
```

The problem is that when the planes are inside the sphere I get ***true*** and ***false*** basically all the time until all the planes leave the sphere. At that point I have a ***false*** and no more ***true***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Box3` is not what you want to use to calculate sphere and plane collisions because the box won't respect the sphere's curvature, nor will it follow the plane's rotation.

Three.js has a class [`THREE.Sphere`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Sphere) that is closer to what you need. Keep in mind that this class is *not* the same as a `Mesh` with a `SphereGeometry`, this is more of a math helper that doesn't render to the canvas. You can use its [`.containsPoint()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Sphere.containsPoint) method for what you need:

```
var sphereCalc = new THREE.Sphere( center, radius );
var point = new THREE.Vector3(10, 4, -6);

detectCollision() {
    var collided = sphereCalc.containsPoint(point);

    if (collided) {
        console.log("Point is in sphere");
    } else {
        console.log("No collision");
    }

    return collided;
}
```

You'll have to apply transforms and check all 4 points of each plane in a loop. Notice there's a [`Sphere.intersectsPlane()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Sphere.intersectsPlane) method that sounds like it would do this for you, but it's not the same because it uses an *infinite* plane to calculate the intersection, not one with a defined width and height, so don't use this.

#### Edit:

To clarify, each plane typically has 4 verts, so you'll have to check each vertex [in a `for()` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to see if the sphere contains each one of the 4 points.

Additionally, the plane will probably have been moved and rotated, so its original vertex positions will have a transform matrix applied to them. I think you were already taking this into account in your example, but it would be something like:

```
point.copy(vertex1);
point.applyMatrix4(plane.matrixWorld)
sphereCalc.containsPoint(point);

point.copy(vertex2);
point.applyMatrix4(plane.matrixWorld)
sphereCalc.containsPoint(point);

// ... and so on
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your time and your good explanation :) but something isn't clear : _"You'll have to apply transforms and check all 4 points of each plane in a loop"_. Can you be a little bit more precise on what I should use to do this ? (I'm a beginner with ThreeJS)

Comment: Sure, I added a clarification to my answer.